# Craft Commerce product item price showing incorrect

Tags: craft3, plugin-craftcommerce2

If I use the following format to show an item price:

```
.defaultVariant.salePrice|currency('GBP')
```

or

```
.defaultVariant.salePrice|commerceCurrency(cart.currency)
```

the website is returns as:

```
9,99 £
```

Instead of what is expected:

> £9.99

Has anyone ever seen this before?
I am using Craft CMS 3.28 and Commerce Pro 2.1.10.

Comment: I think this is very likely to be a locale issue - see: https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/22179/product-price-format-in-euro

Comment: Yes, I think you are correct. I have setup the same dev environment on another PC and its showing correctly so something is up on that machine.
I cannot mark your response as an answer to give you the rep so mentioned you below. If you wanted to post it as an answer, I will edit. 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: It converted my 'trivial response' to a comment.  I can live without the points :)

Answer (score 1):

As Jeremy Daalder pointed out, Its the local system settings causing this. 
A workaround is available in the link he posted.